# AttributeError: 'WordListCorpusReader' object has no attribute '_LazyCorpusLoader__reader_cls' for nltk stopwords

Tags: python, nltk, dask

While trying to load stopwords using below import statement at dask like below, I am getting a weird error saying that **'WordListCorpusReader' object has no attribute '_LazyCorpusLoader__reader_cls'** for nltk stopwords:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def remove_stop_words(text):
  stop_words = stopwords.words("english") # line that throws the error
  # removing words from text that is present in stopwords and return cleaned_text without stopwords
  return cleaned_text

def process(doc):
  return doc.apply(lambda x: remove_stop_words(x))

df = dd.read_csv(...)
df["cleaned_text"] = df["text"].map_partitions(process)
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please see the [ask] guide - specifically, whenever posting about errors please be sure to post the complete [traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) - it includes lots of helpful information that is vital for us to get the complete picture of what's going wrong. Thanks!